# Ember js detect save on model in application

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to figure out a way of setting a property on the Application controller that observes or can detect when a model in the application is saving.

Ideally what I am trying to achieve is a save button that turns into a spinner when the model is being saved - giving the user visual feedback of the save.

The obvious way seems to be manually setting a variable on the application controller pre and post save but ideally I would like to avoid this in place of a property that can observe when the application is saving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `isSaving` property on the model.

Comment: This was definitely the obvious solution and very ember. It was as simple as adding a 'model.isSaving' class binding to my element(s) in the template and there you have it! Easy application saving states.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use jquery's `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop`.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  beforeModel: function(){
    this.setupAjaxMonitor();
  },
  setupAjaxMonitor: function(){
    var self = this;
    $(document)
      .ajaxStart(function(){ self.startAjax(); })
      .ajaxStop(function(){ self.stopAjax(); } );
  },
  startAjax: function(){
    console.log('ajax starting');
  },
  stopAjax: function(){
    console.log('ajax stopping');
  }
});
```

Comment: this approach will catch ANY ajax request, for this model or any other.

Comment: that's what his questions said, `...Application controller that observes or can detect when a model in the application is saving.`  he didn't say when the model in the application route is saving.  The application encompasses the entire application.